# Do you have to include .jsx in script tags in your html?

Tags: reactjs

I see code online for a very simple react app like this:

`index.html`:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    ...
</head>
<body>
    <div id="root"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

And then `index.jsx`:

```
import "babel-polyfill";

import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';

ReactDOM.render(
    <App />,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

But how does the `index.jsx` javascript file even get run if there is no script tag in the `index.html`? Something similar to this: `<script type="text/babel" src="./index.jsx">`?

Comment: I recommend you use Webpack to transpile your code into browser compatible code. You can use `HtmlWebpackPlugin` to inject the bundled file into your index.html.

Comment: This cannot be the whole application. Any chance there's a file names `webpack.config.js`? If so post its contents, most likely is the webpack bundler that takes care of sourcing the script. And yes you have to include `.jsx` files in your HTML, but there are more ways to do it than just by using `<script>` tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expanding on my comment, this is an example of a webpack configuration you might use. This will auto generate an `index.html` file inside `dist` folder with the `index_bundle.js` embedded. `HtmlWebpackPlugin` has options you can pass, but as I said, this is a basic example.

**webpack.config.js**

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

const webpackConfig = {
  entry: 'index.jsx',
  output: {
    path: 'dist',
    filename: 'index_bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: {
      test: /.jsx?$/,
      loader: ['babel-loader'],
      exclude: path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules'),
    }
  }, 
  plugins: [new HtmlWebpackPlugin()]
};
```

Packages you'll need:
`npm install --save-dev webpack babel-loader html-webpack-plugin`

To use run `webpack`.

**EDIT**

You will also need a `.babelrc` file. Basic example:

```
{
    "presets": {
        "es5"
    }
}
```

Comment: It was this project: https://github.com/alexmngn/react-rock-paper-scissors

Comment: @1290 You should be able to run `npm run dev` to spin up a development server using `webpack-dev-server`. This won't create a `dist/` folder, but rather keep the files in memory. If you want to build the `dist/` folder you can run `npm run build`. You should check out that project's `package.json` scripts.